# In X2, how does Stryker know it is not Wolverine but Mystique?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2

In *X2: X-Men United* (2003), when Mystique goes into the dam with Wolverine's appearance, how does Stryker recognise it is not Wolverine?

In the French version of the movie he says something along the lines of "I always recognise my work", but that seems to me a very light explanation considering Mystique can take anyone's appearance, voice, behaviour etc.

Comment: He says "If there's one thing I know more than anyone else, it's my own work." He obviously feels there's something "off" and since he knows Mystique can imitate others...

Comment: Because it's dam obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing in the [film script](https://thescriptsavant.com/movies/XMen_2.pdf) or [official novelisation](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_2_(novel)) that indicates *precisely* what Stryker saw. We're left with the impression that he simply knows Logan well enough to spot that his mannerisms aren't right.

> INT. STRYKER'S BASE - NORTH CORRIDOR - MOMENTS LATER
>
> Logan is led down a corridor by Anne and the soldiers, arms and
> feet shackled, guns to his head. Stryker waits for them at the
> end. As he approaches Logan, staring him closely in the eyes,
> the cocky grin on his face suddenly fades.
>
> **STRYKER:** *Who do you think you're looking at?*
>
> Anne looks puzzled.
>
> **ANNE REYNOLDS:** *Sir?*
>
> **STRYKER:** (to Logan) *You do such a good impression on video, but in person...*
>
> He lifts a GUN to Logan's head, finger on the trigger...

and

> Stryker was grinning broadly as he approached the prisoner, but with each stride his expression changed, triumph gradually giving way to confusion. His eyes narrowed as he began to examine Logan more and more intently.
> He nodded, then asked, “Who do you think you’re looking at?”
> The troopers had no idea what he meant. The answer was obvious to them.
> “Sir?” asked Lyman.
> Stryker shook his head. “The one thing I know better than anyone else . . . is my own work.”
> He turned his back and said, “Shoot it.”

Answer (score 3):

I think Stryker has studied Wolverine for years. So he know how Wolverine behaves, not just how he looks.

Wolverine is like an animal. Mystique can take the form of anyone, but she can't imitate the behavior of someone like Wolverine.

Comment: "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content."  

We prefer longer answers with citations to back up them up. Your answer would be greatly improved if it were more thought out and had some evidence to back it up rather than just a few sentences beginning with "I think."

Comment: We would prefer something more concrete than an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple.

"If there's one thing I know more than anyone, it's my work. Shoot him."

We all know Mystique can change into anyone and Stryker knew as well. Wolverine wouldn't die from those guns if it was truly him.

So to me, it was his way to confirm the real wolf.

Comment: That's why he wasn't worried about being wrong, maybe